# importing csv dataframe and convert it into string in python

Tags: python, string, csv

I am importing my table with has only one column and 2000 rows. the column includes longs DNA sequences with different length;

```
import pandas as pd
dna=pd.read_csv("mydna.csv",header=None)
```

I need to access some dna and convert the column into strings one by one:

```
samples=dna.loc[:10]
```

then I realized that it automatically just takes only few sequences and use `...` for rest of it.it considers all of them with the same length and insert `...` for the rest of the dna sequence. this is how my data is look like, **literary**:

```
print(samples)
                                                   0
0   CGGCCTAACCTGGCTCTCCCAACCTTCAAGCGGCCGGGACCCCGCC...
1   GAGAAAGTAACTGGGTGGCCTCCTCAGTCTCTCCACCACTCAGATT...
2   AAGAACTCCTCCAGGCTCTGACCACTCTCCCAGCCTCGCACAGCGC...
3   GGGAGGCTGAGGCAGGGGGATTGCTTGAGCCCAGGACTTTGAGAAG...
4   GAGTACAGTGGTACGATCTCGGCTCACTGCAGCCTCAACCTCCCAG...
5   GAAACAAATGGATTTTTTTACTACAAATCTCCAGGTTTTTTGGGTT...
6   TCATCTTCCGCACCCGAGCCCCGGGCTCACTCGCTGGGGCTGCCGG...
7   CACAATAATCAGTATTTCTACACAAAGGAAGCATATCCCCCTATTA...
8   TTTCTGTTTGCTGAGCTGTCACTCAAGCTAAACAGATAGCAACAGG...
9   GTTGCCTAGGCTGATCTTGAACTCCTGGGCTTAAGCAGTCCACCCG...
10  GAACTATGTAACTAGCAGCCTCTGGCTTGTTTTCTACTCCCTGTCC...
```

the problem become worse when I want to count dna contents. it consider `...` and `spaces` and `numbers` as dna strings ! each sequence (row) has different length but is shows all with `77` length.

```
len(str(dna.loc[2]))
   Out[27]: 77

len(str(dna.loc[3]))
Out[28]: 77

str(dna.loc[1])
Out[41]: '0    GAGAAAGTAACTGGGTGGCCTCCTCAGTCTCTCCACCACTCAGATT...\nName: 1, dtype: object'

count_kmers(str(dna.loc[1]), 1) #function that counts dna contents

Out[40]: 
{'\n': 1,' ': 7,',': 1,'.': 3,'0': 1,'1': 1,':': 2,'A': 11,'C': 14,'G': 10,'N': 1,'T': 11,'a': 1,'b': 1,'c': 1,'d': 1,'e': 3,'j': 1,'m': 1,'o': 1,'p': 1,'t': 2,'y': 1}
```

it all wrong;I just need `'A','T','C','G'` which it removes most part of it,and the rest of string is just generated after converting.
How can solve 1) the length of sequence problem?and 2) how to ignore the part `'0    ...\nName: 1, dtype: object'` after converting to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just seems confused about indexing, pandas doesn't modify your data, `...` is just for display, and dna is already a string,

```
>>> dna[0][0]
    'CGGCCTAACCTGGCTCTCCCAACCTTCAAGCGGCCGGGACCCCGCCCGGCCTAACCTGGCTCTCCCAACCTTCAAGCGGCCGGGACCCCGCC'
>>> type(dna[0][0]) == str
     True
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I can not understand why I send it to `count_kmer` function, it counts exact string as it display with `...` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a `DataFrame` and not `Series` (a one-dimensional array), hence the indexing returns a `[1 x 1]` object and not a scalar string.

What you probably want to do is this:

```py
import pandas as pd

dna = pd.read_csv("mydna.csv",header=None)[0]  # note the [0]

assert isinstance(dna[0], str)

count_kmers(dna[1], 1)  # no need to use str() or .loc now
```

Comment: thank for your reply. Now is another problem. when I execute this I receive this error `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`. Do you have suggestion to solve this?thx

Comment: @Cina sounds like you're trying to use the `dna` Series object as a key to a dict or something else.